# How to deal with appendchunk and getchunk methods?

Tags: oracle, vb6

```
 Private Function ShowPic()
 Dim bytedata() As Byte
 Dim destfile As Integer
 Dim file As String
 Dim filelen As Long
 Dim numlock As Double
 Dim leftover As Long
 Const blocksize = 100000

 file = App.Path & "\image1.jpeg"

   destfile = FreeFile
   Open file For Binary Access Write As destfile

 filelen = RES(0).ActualSize
        numlock = filelen / blocksize
            leftover = filelen Mod blocksize

   bytedata() = RES(0).GetChunk(leftover)
        Put destfile, , bytedata()
 For i = 1 To numlock
      bytedata() = RES(0).GetChunk(blocksize)
        Put destfile, , bytedata()
 Next i

Close destfile
Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\image1.jpeg")
RES.Close
End Function
```

This is my code to fetch image which is stored in database and display into the picture box,whenever I run the code error occur like:`Item cannot found in corresponding ordinal or name`

Comment: what is RES(0) ? could you post the code where RES() is declared and assigned ? .. i think that you are referring to some database fields which do not exist, or are empty

Comment: What line is fqailing and what is the exact error message?